# CSS padding to input text focus area

Tags: css, input, focus, padding

I have an input text. When focus / selected text it adds a blue background to it. It's not as high as the input field. Is it possible to have padding on the focus area?

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" value="My text">
```

**CSS**

```
input {
  padding: 10px;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
}
```

**Fiddle**

Select the text to see focus background. Is it possible to have padding on this background?

https://jsfiddle.net/fpjc9pLy/

Comment: only border is different in Chrome when focused, What browser are you using?

Comment: Google Chrome but I want it to work with Firefox and Edge as well.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you want

Comment: Just add one more css property `outline: 0;` in your css - [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/harishkommuri/fpjc9pLy/5/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you select the text only the text gets highlighted blue not the input field. So what you are suggesting i.e. to add padding to the highlighted text is not possible.

One workaround can be to change the input field background and font color on focus. Change it back to normal on focus out.

```
$('#txt').focus(function() {
    $('#txt').css('background-color','#0A78FF');
    $('#txt').css('color','#fff');
  });

  $('#txt').focusout(function() {
    $('#txt').css('background-color','white');
    $('#txt').css('color','#000');
  })
```

Try this : http://plnkr.co/edit/6UHBdkfNnHDmKf56fzrn?p=preview

Comment: ... `input:focus{background-color:#0A78FF;color:#fff;}` https://jsfiddle.net/ryneb6bc/

Comment: Oops how can I skip this.. better way to do it. Thanks @CodeiSir for pointing it out.

Answer (score 2):

This area is the `::selection` pseudo element, which is handled differently on different browsers and operating systems. It has been a working draft in CSS3 but has been removed before it became a recommendation status.

It is currently readded as a working draft for CSS4.

It can be used at the moment (for Firefox with the `-moz` prefix) but it only applies to the following rules:

- color
- background-color
- cursor
- outline
- text-decoration
- text-emphasis-color
- text-shadow

More information: [::selection - CSS | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::selection)

The standard area of `::selection` depends on how the browser renders it. it can't be expanded by using CSS.

In general Chrome has a different font size compared to Firefox and thus highlights a different area.